# deque prints back element instead of the front using front()

Tags: c++, deque

I am using dque to push some elements that I read from a file to the back of the deque but when I print them from the front I only get the last element

```
  fgets(line,100,file);
  qu.push_back(line);
  fgets(line,100,file);
  qu.push_back(line);
  fgets(line,100,file);
  qu.push_back(line);
  fgets(line,100,file);
  qu.push_back(line);

  while(!qu.empty())
            {
                puts(qu.front());
                qu.pop_front();
            }
```

sample input

```
a
b
c
d
```

output

```
d
d
d
d
```

Thank you

Comment: So debug your code, then fix it!

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment !!!
if I didn't I wouldn't have asked

Comment: Regardless, this isn't a "debug my code for me" crowdsourcing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided the declarations for `line` and `qu`, but I can guess they are

```
char line[100];
std::dequeue<char*> qu;
```

This means `qu` stores pointers to an external (to `qu`) buffer with characters in it. In your program, you have just a single buffer (`line`), whose address gets pushed repeatedly into `qu`, but whose contents get overwritten with each `fgets` call.

While you are learning C++, try to stay away from pointers as much as you can. So, instead of using `char*` for strings, use `std::string`:

```
std::string line;
std::deque<std::string> qu;

getline(std::cin, line);
qu.push_back(line);
getline(std::cin, line);
qu.push_back(line);
getline(std::cin, line);
qu.push_back(line);
getline(std::cin, line);
qu.push_back(line);

while(!qu.empty())
{
    std::cout << qu.front() << std::endl;
    qu.pop_front();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,
I understand the problem now your answer solved it.